# Older word for stakeout

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing a medieval fantasy story where my characters are looking for a serial killer, and need to go on a stakeout. However, the term stakeout didn't sound right for medieval times, and it turns out it was coined around the 1940s. Is there a similar word that sounds less modern?

Comment: You might find that "serial killer" is a modern concept/term too.

Comment: I had to look up the meaning of "stakeout" on google. I suspect it is rather more used in America than it is in the UK.  I've no idea what word might have been used in the middle ages, but I would probably have said "undercover reconnaisance".

Comment: @KillingTime Yeah, I'm not using that term in the book even if the concept is.

Comment: As you say it is a medieval “fantasy” story. Take the poetic license to use a current term.

Comment: A watch. This is an old term used at sea and perhaps more generally in the military.

Comment: @Xanne Yes. "Officer of the Watch" is still used in the Royal Navy - and possibly other English-speaking navies. The role is performed by a deck officer, who is responsible for the safety of the ship in all its aspects, including watch and look-out for any threats to the ship.

Comment: @Xanne That might work. Feel free to make that an answer if you'd like.

Comment: Yup, **watch** or **guard**. That usage predates the Ceasars.  https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Psalms-141-3/